# resize images in a folder with imagemagick and move to another with specific name for file

Tags: imagemagick

I need to take file from folder `Images`
and move it to folder `test`
and have them renamed

image.jpg -> image_big.jpg

i do that: `mogrify -resize 200 -path images/../test/ images/*.*`
works great!
when i try to change the name of the file like this

```
mogrify -resize 200 -format %t_big.%e -path images/../test/ images/*.*
```

i get the file name something like image._big.big

i tried with convert (but i will have 3000 images and i read that it uses the ram and not doing it like mogrify

```
convert images/*.jpg -resize 200 images/../test/
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

For `mogrify` you an use the [-set](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#set) & [-fromat](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#format) options.

```
mogrify -resize 200x -set filename:f "big.%e" \
        -format "%[filename:f]" -path test/ images/*
```

This will give destination filenames of "image.big.jpg"

For `convert`, use bash to iterator over all 3000 files

```
for infile in `ls images/*.jpg`
do
  convert $infile -resize 200x -set filename:f "%t_big.%e" test/%[filename:f]
done
```

This will give you filenames like "image_big.jpg"